# How to render a Bitmap image in MVC 4 (using C#.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone tell me how can I display a bitmap image into a cshtml page?

Controller:

```
var sigToImg = new SignatureToImage();
var signatureImage = sigToImg.SigJsonToImage(surveyQuestionProxyViewModel.SurveyToolQuestionViewModel.UserSurveyAnswer.AnswerText);
surveyQuestionProxyViewModel.SurveyToolQuestionViewModel.UserSurveyAnswer.AnswerTextSig = signatureImage;

//signatureImage is System.drwaing.bitmap image

html = this.RenderViewToString(@"~/Views/PrintAsPdf/SurveyTool/_ExportSurveyToolQuestion.cshtml", surveyQuestionProxyViewModel);
```

Now I need to render `surveyQuestionProxyViewModel.SurveyToolQuestionViewModel.UserSurveyAnswer.AnswerTextSig` into view like below:

```
<div>
    <img src="@Model.SurveyToolQuestionViewModel.UserSurveyAnswer.AnswerTextSig" alt="Signature Image"/>
</div>
```

But nothing appears in view at run time. How can I render this.

Comment: I think you should consider converting the Bitmap into a PNG.

Comment: Try encoding it in base 64.